# Kivy Repeating Actions

Tags: python, kivy

I've been playing around kivy's touch inputs, however I've noticed that my functions get called multiple times despite a button being pushed only once.

```
def on_touch_down(self,touch):
    with self.canvas:
        if self.clearcanvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
        Color(*self.color)
        touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y),width =3)
    self.actions()
    return True


def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if self.clearcanvas:
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
        self.linecoord = touch.ud['line'].points


def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    pass


def actions(self):
    #if shape is accepted by user
    if self.clearcanvas:
        def acceptshape(obj):


            # test to see if shape overlaps
            self.linecoordtuple = []
            for i in range(0,len(self.linecoord)-1,2):
                x = round(self.linecoord[i])
                y = round(self.linecoord[i+1])
                self.linecoordtuple.append((x,y))
            crossingcheck = len(self.linecoordtuple)==len(set(self.linecoordtuple))


            # if no overlap and a shape is drawn, plots mesh
            if self.convexsmoothing:
                if len(self.linecoord)>0:
                    self.clearcanvas = False
                    with self.canvas:
                        self.canvas.clear()
                        Color(*self.color)
                        self.build_mesh()
                else:
                    print "Invalid Shape"
                    self.canvas.clear()
                    self.clearcanvas = True
            else:
                if len(self.linecoord)>0 and crossingcheck:
                    self.clearcanvas = False
                    with self.canvas:
                        self.canvas.clear()
                        Color(*self.color)
                        self.build_mesh()
                else:
                    print "Invalid Shape"
                    self.canvas.clear()
                    self.clearcanvas = True

        keepbtn.bind(on_press=acceptshape)
```

For example, When I push accept button and the shape is not valid,, I get repeated messages:
Invalid Shape
Invalid Shape
Invalid Shape
Invalid Shape
Invalid Shape

Is there something I'm missing when it comes to motion events?

Comment: Can you paste a full runnable example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time the `on_touch_down()` method is called, you create a brand new `acceptshape()` function and bind it to the button. So when you press the button, it will call a separate `acceptshape()` function for each time you touched previously. You should create a single function (or method) and bind it to the button once, when the widget is first created.

FYI - Kivy does not perform collision checking when dispatching touch events - it's up to you to do such checks (or not, if you want to receive all touch events). You can do this by wrapping the function body with a collision check like so:

```
def on_touch_down(self,touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        with self.canvas:
            if self.clearcanvas:
                self.canvas.clear()
            Color(*self.color)
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y),width =3)
        self.actions()
        return True
```

Make sure that you only return `True` inside the collision check, otherwise you may end up cancelling touch events when you don't mean to. Note that this only applies to the touch events, `on_touch_down`/`on_touch_move`/`on_touch_up`. The `ButtonBehavior` events `on_press` and `on_release`, like those on the `Button` widget, do perform collision checks.

Comment: I've tried to bind it once during the button creation:                           
keepbtn.bind(on_press=painter.acceptshape()), (with painter being an object that contains the acceptshape function), but it says that None is not callable?

Comment: If you do `on_press=painter.acceptshape()`, you're calling the function and assigning the return value as the on_press handler. Try using `on_press=painter.acceptshape` to pass the function itself instead.